# Раскрывающийся блок с описанием поверх другого

Tags: javascript, html, css

Поскажите, как грамотно сверстать и "оживить" данную задачу. Необходимо, чтобы блок с описанием вверху (синий) при клике на "подробнее" раскрывался поверх остальной информации и растягивался на всю высоту текста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: давай исходный код и напишу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```js
$('.card-more').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
    $card = $this.closest('.card'),
    $cardTextMore = $card.find('.card-text-more');

  if (!$card.hasClass('on')) {
    $card.addClass('on');
    $cardTextMore.slideDown(200);
    $this.html('Slide up');
  } else {
    $card.removeClass('on');
    $cardTextMore.slideUp(200);
    $this.html('More text');
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font: 1rem/1.5rem Tahoma;
}

.card {
  max-width: 16rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: .875rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0px .5rem 1rem #3c85f3;
  padding-top: 12.5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem .75rem;
}

.card-rate {
  margin: 0 0 .25rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
}

.card-meta {
  color: #777;
  font-size: .75rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: .75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #3c85f3;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.card-top {
  background: #3c85f3;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: .875rem .875rem 0 0;
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card-title {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: .75rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.card-more {
  color: #faca50;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.card-more:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.card.on {
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.card.on .card-top {
  border-radius: .875rem;
  height: auto;
}

.card-text-more {
  display: none;
}



.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
<div class="row">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-top">
      <h3 class="card-title">
        Title 1
      </h3>
      
      <div class="card-text">
        <div class="card-text-prev">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni et, quasi magnam sint hic, libero at distinctio tenetur. Nostrum, sed , libero at distinctio tenetur , libero at distinctio tenetur...
        </div>
        <div class="card-text-more">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam cupiditate, fugit obcaecati! Amet minus voluptate nesciunt, totam esse vitae doloremque quisquam id distinctio iste fugit, ducimus iusto repellat est repudiandae! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi culpa natus tempore tempora voluptatum. Error delectus, autem quae omnis quo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed fugit perferendis aperiam, tempora odio sint distinctio atque, quibusdam suscipit? Beatae!
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <a href="#" class="card-more">
        More text
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum.
          </td>
          <td>
            $20 000
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum.
          </td>
          <td>
            $20 000
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum.
          </td>
          <td>
            $20 000
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <h6 class="card-rate">
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </h6>
      <div class="card-meta">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, perspiciatis?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-top">
      <h3 class="card-title">
        Title 2
      </h3>
      
      <div class="card-text">
        <div class="card-text-prev">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni et, quasi magnam sint hic, libero at distinctio tenetur. Nostrum, sed , libero at distinctio tenetur , libero at distinctio tenetur...
        </div>
        <div class="card-text-more">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam cupiditate, fugit obcaecati! Amet minus voluptate nesciunt, totam esse vitae doloremque quisquam id distinctio iste fugit, ducimus iusto repellat est repudiandae! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi culpa natus tempore tempora voluptatum. Error delectus, autem quae omnis quo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed fugit perferendis aperiam, tempora odio sint distinctio atque, quibusdam suscipit? Beatae!
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <a href="#" class="card-more">
        More text
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum.
          </td>
          <td>
            $20 000
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum.
          </td>
          <td>
            $20 000
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum.
          </td>
          <td>
            $20 000
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <h6 class="card-rate">
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
      </h6>
      <div class="card-meta">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, perspiciatis?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Фантастика! Спасибо большое! Хотел бы еще узнать, если таких блоков на странице несколько, как можно сделать, чтобы по клику на "подробнее" отрывался конкретный блок, а не все сразу.

Comment: @MaksimChernyshev, исправила

Answer (score 1):

Можно <s>вообще без JS</s> почти без js сделать.

```
<style>
details[open] {
  display: contents;  
}
details[open] summary {
  display: none;
}
details[open] + .next_block {
  display: none;
}    
details a {
  display: block;
}
</style>

Текст 
<details>
  <summary>Полное описание</summary>
  скрытое/показанное содержимое
  <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.removeAttribute('open')">спрятать</a>
</details>
<div class="next_block">
   блок после спойлера
</div>
```

Возможно там требуется больше CSS. Но этого должно быть достаточно для понимания как оно работает.

<s>https://jsfiddle.net/4jz0ouvd/</s>

https://jsfiddle.net/kx9m2nhr/

Comment: А обратно свернуть?

Comment: @HamSter исправил